# Importing big data from Application insights to PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I want to use the analytic data from my app-insights (billions of rows) in PowerBI. I read Microsoft documentation but the more I've read, the more confused I've got.

For example I've found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-application-insights) which has a "Deprecated" sign on top of it and says to check [export analytic query functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-power-bi#export-analytics-queries)

So here are my questions:

1. The analytic functionality seems as if it is exporting the results of one query to the power Bi. What happens when you setup **scheduled refresh**?

   - So basically, does it keep the old data as well? Because [app-insight keeps the data only for 90 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-data-retention-privacy) if not, how can I do it? I need to be able to compare data for some years.
2. Does the PowerBi host the data or just the reports that you create for that? (I sound stupid in a way, but I couldn't find the answer)
3. I've set up [continues export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry) on app-insights. How should I set the powerBi to read from blobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer some of your questions.

1 - When you schedule a refresh, a new dataset is retrieved from AI. The old data is gone.

2 - Powerbi does not host the data when using AI analytics queries as a source, the report does that.

3 - As you can see in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-azure-and-power-bi#transform-shape-and-merge-your-cloud-data) you can add a azure storage blob datasource easily. Just use the Get Data option and select Azure Storage Blob

Furthermore:

> I need to be able to compare data for some years.

You might want to generate one or more readmodels for your reporting as having to read potentially gigabytes of data from storage is not very efficient. You could use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) and / or [Azure Data Lake Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-lake-analytics/) to prepare the data for you by transforming and aggregate the data stored in blobs by the continuous export of AI.

Comment: One limitation to keep in mind, is that the tabular model only allows 1,999,999,997 distinct values in a column. This can be seen in the SSAS tabular model limitation docs, which is the same tool that power BI is using.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. :) what do you consider when you generate read models? Also, I didn't see any option to do the continues export to Azure Data Lake. Should I do it as app-Insights --> BlobStorage--> Data Lake--> PowerBI?

Comment: Azure Data Lake Analytics can, like Azure Data Factory, connect to blob storage, so it can read the files AI generates.

Comment: About the readmodels, I'd say try to model/describe the data you want to see at the various reports and then create an azure data factory pipeline and/or azure data lake analytics to create that model